# 'Int' is not identical to 'String' - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, datepicker

In this function I'm trying to get the data from the UIDatePicker and subtract 5 from it. For example if in the UIDatePicker said 7:15 AM it would subtract from the hours and be 2:15 AM. The modified code does not work on the line where I'm giving it to my label the error says **'Int' is not identical to 'String'**. The working code is the original version where it works whatever I put into the Date Picker it shows the date the user chose so if 7:15 AM it would show up as 7:15 AM without subtracting anything.

**DatePicker that hooks up with the Storyboard**

```
@IBOutlet weak var theDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
```

**Original Code without the .toInt()**

```
func handler(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        var timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

        var strDate = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(theDatePicker.date)

        hoursLeftLabel.text = strDate

    }
```

**Modified Code**

```
func handler(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        var timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

        var intDate = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(theDatePicker.date).toInt()

        hoursLeftLabel.text = intDate

    }
```

If you have any questions or need any clarifications please comment down below

Comment: Isn't the compiler error message as clear as possible? You assign an `Int` to a `String` property.

Comment: Then how would you be able to subtract a number; 5 from the UIDatePicker?

Comment: *Hint:* What does `theDatePicker.date` represent? How could this value be modified to represent a date that is 5 hours earlier? – *Hint #2:* http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @MartinR it represents whatever is in the DatePicker at the time.

Comment: And *how* is the date/time represented?

Comment: As a PM and AM? Or as one number instead of three separate numbers @MartinR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64257/discussion-between-grapeapplesauce-and-martin-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
 hoursLeftLabel.text = "\(intDate)"
```

This should work because you create a string which contains the int date.

The error Int is not identical to string means that you are passing an Int where a string is needed. The error could indeed be more precise like saying wrong type or something like this

Edit:
I would recommend you to do the date calculations like this:

```
let newDate = theDatePicker.date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-5*60*60) //-5 Hours
//now you can display your date like this:
hoursLeftLabel.text = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(newDate)
```

Comment: How do I make it so that it the UIDatePicker - The Time Right Now which is "\(startHours):\(startMinutes):\(startSeconds)"

Comment: Have a look at NSDateComponents